# Global variable value is not appearing in else if statement of JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm defining a global array `Arr` and inserting few values inside the array in **if condition** I can see all the values of array `Arr` in **if condition** but when I try to use the `Arr` in **else if condition** I'm getting the length of `Arr` as 0 (zero). i don't know what is the reason. I need help and I'll be thankful if some can put some light on it. Please edit this code if someone knows the issue.

```
Arr=[]; // Global Variable

for(var k=1; k<=2; k++){

if (k ==1){

//Inserting the values in array Arr

//My Arr array is having value Arr[{Firstname:"xyz", Lastname:"abc"}{Firstname:"xyz1", Lastname:"abc1"}]


Console.log(Arr); //Here I can see all the values inside the Array Arr in console.


}else if (k ==1){

console.log(Arr.length); //Here I'm getting  Array value as 0


}

}
```

Comment: empty arrays have length equal to 0. What is your expectation?

Comment: You have errors in your if -else if statement. The else if should never hit as you have it here as it is the same condition as if k==1...

Comment: Please show us how do you insert elements in the array, since the code is commented out.

Comment: Your `if` and `else if` conditions are the same! Your `else if` code won't ever run.

Comment: Please show us the actual code.  Your comments indicating that you insert stuff into the array replace the code that is likely exactly what we need to see.

Comment: Could it be that you tried to go the json way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that you are loading the Array inside the "if" statement.  which would mean that it is correct that the else would have no values.

Comment: So what should i do to resolve it. Please tell me is there any other way

Comment: If you need access to the variable inside the else, the the solution would be to load the array outside of the if condition.
Just load the array before the "if" statement.

Comment: Actually, can't you just load your array outside of the for loop?